# Bokeh callback to change source data and hover tooltip

Tags: bokeh

I'm using Bokeh to plot X/Y data.

The X and Y values are created separately and combined into one dataframe that would feed the chart.

Can someone please explain the best way to accomplish the following:

- The global `new_df` created is not being used as a source when the update source callback is run. Is this because of the new column names/ shape of the new data source?
- The Hover Tool settings are initialized only for the original X/Y data. So it won't pull in the "Extra_Info" columns in the second `new_df` example. 
   What is the best way to make the Hover Tool accept the extra columns? 
   Is re-setting the Hover Tool inside the callback function the way to do this?

Here is my semi-working example.
Appreciate any help.

```
#Imports
import bokeh
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool


#Creating first data source
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (3000, 2)), 
                   columns = ["X", "Y"], 
                   index = [str(i) for i in range(1, 3000 + 1)])

pointchart_source = ColumnDataSource(df1)
pointchart = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 700)
pointchart_glyph = pointchart.circle("X", "Y", source = pointchart_source, size = 3.5)

hover=HoverTool(tooltips = [("(X,Y)", "($x{1,111},$y{1,111})")])
pointchart.add_tools(hover)



#Button and calback to switch source data
def on_switch_button_click():
    global new_df
    pointchart_source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(new_df)

    #Should probably plugging in new data as a dictionary.
    #pointchart_source.data = {'X': newdataframe['X'].values, 'Y': newdataframe['Y'].values, 'index': newdataframe.index.values}

switch_button = Button(label = "Switch", button_type = "success")
switch_button.on_click(on_switch_button_click)


#Option I
#Making a changed data source. Combined two 1D into a DF.
x=pd.DataFrame({'X_Value_For_Plot':[randint(1, 100) for i in range(0,10)], 'Common_Column':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})
y=pd.DataFrame({'Y_Value_For_Plot':[randint(1, 100) for i in range(0,10)], 'Common_Column':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})

new_df = x.merge(y,on='Common_Column')



#Option II
#Making another data source with extra columns for the Hover Tool. 
x=pd.DataFrame({'X_Value_For_Plot':[randint(1, 100) for i in range(0,10)], 
                'X_Extra_Info':['abc','cba','sgc','ddh','eda','fdv','gdy','hsy','dsi','jdu'],
                'Common_Column':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})


y=pd.DataFrame({'Y_Value_For_Plot':[randint(1, 100) for i in range(0,10)], 
                'Y_Extra_Info':['hsa','bsv','dyc','sdd','eac','eyf','scg','dyh','isq','jst'],
                'Common_Column':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})

new_df = x.merge(y,on='Common_Column')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT you are making things more complicated than necessary. If can produce lists, arrays, or series for each of the columns separately, which seems to be what you said, then you can just construct the dict yourself:

```
source.data = {
    'X': the_x_data,
    'Y': the_y_data,
    'X_Extra_Info': the_extra_data,
}
```

As long as all the dict values have the same length (which they *must*, in any case) there is no need to put things in Pandas first.

Comment: Thank you! Also did this in the callback to accommodate the extra data and rename the X/Y:

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("(Label_X,Label_Y)", "(@X, @Y)"),('X_Extra_Info', '@X_Extra_Info')])               
   pointchart.add_tools(hover)